# NodeJS: debugging a server side project in Chrome for the benefits of the Developer Tools

Tags: node.js

I love Chrome's Developer Tools. They've come a long way since FireFox dominated with Firebug. Today . I would love working on my Node.js project with those Developer Tools rather than Webstorm's Debug Tool Window. I *am* using NPM libraries like:

- Request
- Q
- lodash
- javascript-state-machine
- stackify-logger
- winston

However most of them are just Node.js versions of client-side libraries. Is there a way, a magical way, that I could make this happen. Work client side with chrome and gulpify my project for server. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "work client-side and gulpify my project for server". If you are wanting to use the Chrome Dev Tools for server side debugging, try [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) or [iron-node](https://github.com/s-a/iron-node).

Comment: @Guy: this is the right answer. node-inspector does exactly what you want in the magical way you describe

Comment: This is awesome stuff